# What's the best and easiest way to create a UITableView form?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

What's the best and easiest way to create a UITableView form?

It's getting messy and tedious to create a form for data entry using the UItableView -- and maybe I am missing something because I see these uitableview forms everywhere in iPhone but they are so PITA to create.

Comment: iOS 5.0/Storyboards/static tables (that much has been stated publicly, and we can elucidate after mid October) - you are correct, it's a PITA currently, so you're probably doing it right

Comment: Apple *really* needs to add standard editable tableview cell types to UIKit. It's such a glaring omission.

Answer (score 8):

I found https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog

Comment: UpVote bcse its my project! It indeed was created to solve exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: @EduardoScoz Very very nice work. This is what Apple should have included with UIKit from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm). Looks powerful and up-to-date.